# Unable to fold divs in Sublime Text 3

Tags: sublimetext3

Only some of the arrow icons in the gutter are rended; some aren't and, therefore, can't be clicked.
I have Emmet installed and its shortcuts don't work on those divs either.

Only the ones with adjacent arrows can be folded.

Any tips?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I see you can only fold those divs that begin from that thick gray line. In bottom right corner you should see Spaces: X(X is a number, I guess you have 4), click on that and change it to 2 spaces. That should solve the problem.

EDIT: Also I guess it is a good practice to change indentation to spaces.

Comment: Thank you so much; This wasn't intuitive to me and I didn't have time to go through the whole manual;

Google searches didn't provide any relevant answer on this.

Comment: Can you please explain this answer more? First, not all users will have “Spaces: X” in the bottom bar. Second, the answer should say what this is and how it is related to the question (I cannot imagine how it could possibly be related).